# Errors while running native code from Java

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, g++, shared-libraries

I am very new to programming using JNI and I cannot run a method I have written in C++ from Java. I am following [this](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/tutorials/j-jni/j-jni-pdf.pdf) tutorial. I have a cpp source file "cpp.cpp" and a java file "Cpp.java". The steps that I followed are:

1. Wrote the java code, declared the native method, created a shared library using `System.loadLibrary("libcpp")`.
2. Compiled the code using `javac Cpp.java`.
3. Created C++ header file using `javah Cpp`.
4. Wrote the cpp code with the native methods declared in the java file, and some other methods that I am calling internally from it.
5. Compiled this code using `g++ -fPIC -shared cpp.cpp -o libcpp.so` and got the shared library file in the same directory.

Now I am trying to run the java code using `java Cpp` but I am getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no libcpp in java.library.path
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1867)
   at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
   at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
   at Cpp.main(Cpp.java:17)
```

I read other questions but most of them are running on Windows. How can I do this correctly using Ubuntu?

Below is the directory structure:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 piyush piyush    450 May 17 11:56 Cpp.h
-rw-rw-r-- 1 piyush piyush  32624 May 17 12:08 cpp.cpp
-rwxrwxr-x 1 piyush piyush  31237 May 17 13:38 libcpp.so
-rw-rw-r-- 1 piyush piyush    831 May 17 14:06 Cpp.java
-rw-rw-r-- 1 piyush piyush    676 May 17 14:07 Cpp.class
```

Comment: As the error says, the library file isn't be found. Make sure it's in the correct directory and you have your search paths set up appropriately.

Comment: @KerrekSB I have the file in the same directory as my java and c++ files, I have not set any path, can you tell me how to do that?

Comment: You created library named `libcpp.so` but in java you using `System.loadLibrary("libCpp")` can you see the difference???????

Comment: @piyushjaiswal edited the question, I changed the library name, the error is still not solved, thanks.

Comment: can you provide the directory structure, `ls -lrt` output?

Comment: @piyushjaiswal Added

Comment: See answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36904131/error-when-using-jni-on-ubuntu-java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-no-in-java-l